# Scaling images from instagram

Tags: swift, imageview, collectionview

In my app, I'm trying to get images from my Instagram account and render them in a collection view. When using

```
self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = false
```

The images scale perfectly. But since the images from the Instagram feed are of different sizes, the images in the collection view are of different sizes. A few are perfect squares, a few are smaller, and a few are rectangles.

I want to have a collection view of images all perfectly of the same size (square in shape) and images maintaining their aspect ratio. How can I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the full photo and maintain aspect ratio, set `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`.

To fill the square `imageView` but show the photo with the correct aspect ratio set `contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` and `clipsToBounds = true`.

Comment: yes, but this renders one photo as a rectangle and one as a square.I'd like to render all of them as perfect square while maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image.Also i donot want to clip any portion of the image.

Comment: @Aravind See my update.  You just had both settings wrong if you're trying to fill squares and maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: Wouldn't the above clip/crop the images to fill the square?

Comment: OK, then just go with my original answer.  If you want the image to fully fit within a square without clipping, then set contentMode to aspectFit and set clipsToBounds to true.  Actually you don't even need to set clipsToBounds, but I always do anyway in case I change content mode later.

Comment: The image is still going to look like a rectangle because it IS a rectangle.  It will just fit within the square bounds of the imageView.

Comment: Yes i tried this too.But on doing that.One image renders as a square and one image renders as rectangle.Depending on the original image.

Comment: You can't have both.  Either you show the full image as a rectangle, or you clip the image to a square by saying contentMode=.scaleAspectFill and clipsToBounds=true.  It's one or the other.

Comment: But i want all of the images to be rendered as a square and scaled properly.Is  there a way to do it?